# GCP Storage - How to create a script that copies all files/folders from one bucket to another, but in a different folder structure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

There is a bucket on GCP in which the folders are named as below.

```
Tests_111/tests.pdf

Tests_112/tests.pdf

AllTests_111/alltests.pdf
...
```

These folders need to be copied into another bucket in the following structure.

```
Tests/111/tests.pdf

Tests/112/tests.pdf

AllTests/111/alltests.pdf
```

---

I basically, just trying to check the folder name to see if it can be spliced by '`_`', which will give me "`Tests`" & "`111`". After that, create a folder with the name "Tests" and a subfolder with the name "`111`" within that one.

I'm new to GCP and gsutils. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Google Cloud Storage does not have folders/directories. The namespace is flat. In your case, you would do an object copy while replacing the first '_' character with a '/' character. Almost any scripting language can do that simple character replacement.

Comment: Are you looking for someone to write code/script for you? We help you solve problems with the code you write. MBHA Phoenix provided a good answer to help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

here an example of code snippet to copy objects from one bucket to another

```
from google.cloud import storage


def copy_blob(
    bucket_name, blob_name, destination_bucket_name, destination_blob_name
):
    """Copies a blob from one bucket to another with a new name."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # blob_name = "your-object-name"
    # destination_bucket_name = "destination-bucket-name"
    # destination_blob_name = "destination-object-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    source_bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    source_blob = source_bucket.blob(blob_name)
    destination_bucket = storage_client.bucket(destination_bucket_name)

    blob_copy = source_bucket.copy_blob(
        source_blob, destination_bucket, destination_blob_name
    )

    print(
        "Blob {} in bucket {} copied to blob {} in bucket {}.".format(
            source_blob.name,
            source_bucket.name,
            blob_copy.name,
            destination_bucket.name,
        )
    )
```

Ref: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/copying-renaming-moving-objects#storage-copy-object-python

So you have only to code the logic to set properly the `destination_blob_name` from the `blob_name`. By the way a blob name is fully qualified, means it include the folder name and the file name like `Tests/111/tests.pdf`